# ** glibc detected *** ./main: free(): invalid next size (fast):

Tags: c++

I'm an Italian guy, so sorry for my BAD english, and sorry if I make some mistake posting this question, but it's my first one, so please be kind with me, thanks!

I'm writing this inline function, and I know that there are a lot of question titled like this one on the forum, but no one of them can help me!

The code is:

```
inline int dapotare (int* i_node,int* j_node,int* q_infr,int *value,double *D,double *Q,int level,int nStart,int nEdge,int nInfrastructureTypes,int *risultato)
{int in_esame,attivi=0,inattivi=0,scope,stop;
int *predecessore = new int [nStart] ;
int **numInattivi= new int* [nStart];
int *comulatore = new int [nStart];;
int *BS = new int [nStart];
bool daCentrale=false;              //se true significa che esiste una y_{i,j}^q=1 dove i è il nodo centrale

for(int i=0;i<nStart;i++)
    numInattivi[i] = new int [nStart];

for(int i=0;i<nStart;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<nStart;j++)
        numInattivi[i][j]=0;
for(int i=0;i<=level;i++)
    if(value[i]==1)
        {attivi++;
        if(i_node[i]==nStart-1)
            {daCentrale=true;
            cout<<"il nodo centrale ha almeno un arco uscente!"<<endl;
            }
        }
    else
        {numInattivi[i_node[i]][j_node[i]]++;
        if(numInattivi[i_node[i]][j_node[i]]==nInfrastructureTypes && numInattivi[i_node[i]][j_node[i]]==nInfrastructureTypes)
            inattivi++;
        }
if(attivi>=nStart-1||attivi+inattivi==nEdge*2||daCentrale/*||inattivi>=nEdge-nStart+1*/)
    {risultato[0]=1;
    risultato[1]=attivi;
    risultato[2]=inattivi;
    for(int actual=0;actual<nStart;actual++)
        delete []numInattivi[actual];
    delete []predecessore;
    delete []comulatore;
    delete []BS;
    return 1;
    }

//definisco i predecessori dei nodi
for(int i=0;i<nStart;i++)                       
    predecessore[i]=-1;
for(int i=0;i<=level;i++)
    if(value[i]==1)
            {if(predecessore[i_node[i]]!=-1)
                {cout<<i_node[i]<<" ha almenno due archi uscenti!"<<endl;
                risultato[0]=1;
                risultato[1]=attivi;
                risultato[2]=inattivi;
                for(int actual=0;actual<nStart;actual++)
                    delete []numInattivi[actual];
                delete []numInattivi;
                delete []predecessore;
                delete []comulatore;
                delete []BS;
                return 1;
                }
            else
                {predecessore[i_node[i]]=j_node[i];
                }
            }
    else
            predecessore[i]=-1;

//controllo che il grafo sia aciclico
for(int i=0;i<=level;i++)                       //controllo che il grafo sia aciclico
    {in_esame=predecessore[i_node[i]];
        for(int j=0;j<level&&in_esame!=-1;j++)  //se predecessore[in_esame]==-1 significa che non ho incontrato cicli
            if(predecessore[in_esame]==i_node[i])
                {cout<<"STAMPA DEI PREDECESSORI:"<<endl;
                for(int actual=0;actual<level;actual++)
                    cout<<"predecessore["<<actual<<"]= "<<predecessore[actual]<<endl;
                cout<<"in_esame="<<in_esame<<endl;
                cout<<i_node[i]<<" crea un ciclo!"<<endl;
                risultato[0]=1;
                risultato[1]=attivi;
                risultato[2]=inattivi;
                //cin>>stop;
                for(int actual=0;actual<nStart;actual++)
                    delete []numInattivi[actual];
                delete []predecessore;
                delete []comulatore;
                delete []BS;
                return 1;
                }
            else
                in_esame=predecessore[in_esame];
    }
//definisco il comulatore di ciascun nodo e controllo che nessun nodo del grafo parziale sia sovraccaricato
for(int i=0;i<nStart-1;i++)     //inizializziamo comulatore
        comulatore[i]=-D[i];
for(int i=0;i<nStart-1;i++)     //definiamo BS
        {BS[i]=0;
        for(int j=0;j<nStart-1;j++)
            if(predecessore[j]==i)  //j è figlio di i
                BS[i]++;
        }
for(int i=0;i<nStart-1;i++)
    cout<<"D["<<i<<"]= "<<D[i]<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<nStart-1;i++)
    cout<<"predecessore["<<i<<"]= "<<predecessore[i]<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<nStart-1;i++)
    cout<<"BS["<<i<<"]= "<<BS[i]<<endl;
cout<<"Prima del comulatore"<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<nStart-1;i++)
        {for(int j=0;j<nStart-1;j++)
            {for(int actual=0;actual<=level;actual++)
                {if(i_node[actual]==j&&value[actual]==1&&BS[j]==0)
                    {comulatore[predecessore[j]]+=comulatore[j];
                    BS[predecessore[j]]--;
                    BS[j]=-1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
for(int i=0;i<nStart-1;i++)
    cout<<"comulatore["<<i<<"]= "<<comulatore[i]<<endl;
for(int actual=0;actual<=level;actual++)
    {if(comulatore[i_node[actual]]>Q[q_infr[actual]]&&value[actual]==1)
        {cout<<i_node[actual]<<" è sovraccaricato: comulaotre["<<i_node[actual]<<"]= "<<comulatore[i_node[actual]]<<" Q[q_infr]="<<Q[q_infr[actual]]<<endl;
        risultato[0]=1;
        risultato[1]=attivi;
        risultato[2]=inattivi;
        for(int actual=0;actual<nStart;actual++)
            delete []numInattivi[actual];
        delete []predecessore;
        delete []comulatore;
        delete []BS;
        return 1;
        }
    }

risultato[0]=0;             //Tutto ok! Non ci interessa il valore degli inattivi e inattivi se non c'è niente da potare
risultato[1]=0;
risultato[2]=0;
for(int actual=0;actual<nStart;actual++)
    delete[] numInattivi[actual];
cout<<"superato il for"<<endl;
delete[] numInattivi;
cout<<"superato numInattivi"<<endl;
delete[] predecessore;
cout<<"superato il predecessore"<<endl;
delete[] comulatore;
cout<<"superato comulatore"<<endl;
delete[] BS;
cout<<"superato BS"<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

And the error returned when I run it is:

```
  *** glibc detected *** ./main: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09cb7d48 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb6567ee2]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x1f)[0xb678f51f]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x1b)[0xb678f57b]
./main[0x8057312]
./main[0x805591a]
./main[0x804a9ab]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb650b4d3]
./main[0x804abd5]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-0805a000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 2360       /home/luca-kun/Desktop/LOG/BranchAndBound/main
0805a000-0805b000 r--p 00011000 07:00 2360       /home/luca-kun/Desktop/LOG/BranchAndBound/main
0805b000-0805c000 rw-p 00012000 07:00 2360       /home/luca-kun/Desktop/LOG/BranchAndBound/main
09cb3000-09cd4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b5843000-b5846000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b5846000-b5848000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 590098     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.15.so
b5848000-b5849000 r--p 00001000 07:00 590098     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.15.so
b5849000-b584a000 rw-p 00002000 07:00 590098     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.15.so
b584a000-b584b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b584b000-b584e000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 590114     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
b584e000-b584f000 r--p 00002000 07:00 590114     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
b584f000-b5850000 rw-p 00003000 07:00 590114     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
b5850000-b589f000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 297406     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.0.0.0
b589f000-b58a0000 r--p 0004e000 07:00 297406     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.0.0.0
b58a0000-b58a2000 rw-p 0004f000 07:00 297406     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.0.0.0
b58a2000-b58a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b58a4000-b58ed000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 297407     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so.0.0.0
b58ed000-b58ee000 r--p 00048000 07:00 297407     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so.0.0.0
b58ee000-b58f0000 rw-p 00049000 07:00 297407     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so.0.0.0
b58f0000-b58f1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b58f1000-b58f2000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300602     /usr/lib/libblacsCinit-openmpi.so.1.1
b58f2000-b58f3000 r--p 00000000 07:00 300602     /usr/lib/libblacsCinit-openmpi.so.1.1
b58f3000-b58f4000 rw-p 00001000 07:00 300602     /usr/lib/libblacsCinit-openmpi.so.1.1
b58f4000-b5987000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 297402     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.0.0.2
b5987000-b5988000 r--p 00093000 07:00 297402     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.0.0.2
b5988000-b5995000 rw-p 00094000 07:00 297402     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.0.0.2
b5995000-b599e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b599e000-b59b3000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300611     /usr/lib/libpord-4.9.2.so
b59b3000-b59b4000 r--p 00014000 07:00 300611     /usr/lib/libpord-4.9.2.so
b59b4000-b59b5000 rw-p 00015000 07:00 300611     /usr/lib/libpord-4.9.2.so
b59b5000-b5a27000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 521780     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
b5a27000-b5a28000 r--p 00071000 07:00 521780     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
b5a28000-b5a29000 rw-p 00072000 07:00 521780     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0.0.0
b5a29000-b5a5a000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300598     /usr/lib/libblacs-openmpi.so.1.1
b5a5a000-b5a5b000 r--p 00030000 07:00 300598     /usr/lib/libblacs-openmpi.so.1.1
b5a5b000-b5a5c000 rw-p 00031000 07:00 300598     /usr/lib/libblacs-openmpi.so.1.1
b5a5c000-b6040000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300606     /usr/lib/libscalapack-openmpi.so.1.8.0
b6040000-b6041000 r--p 005e3000 07:00 300606     /usr/lib/libscalapack-openmpi.so.1.8.0
b6041000-b6043000 rw-p 005e4000 07:00 300606     /usr/lib/libscalapack-openmpi.so.1.8.0
b6043000-b6095000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6095000-b60c0000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 297404     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi_f77.so.0.0.1
b60c0000-b60c1000 r--p 0002a000 07:00 297404     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi_f77.so.0.0.1
b60c1000-b60c2000 rw-p 0002b000 07:00 297404     /usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi_f77.so.0.0.1
b60c2000-b60c3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b60c3000-b60ff000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300610     /usr/lib/libmumps_common-4.9.2.so
b60ff000-b6100000 r--p 0003b000 07:00 300610     /usr/lib/libmumps_common-4.9.2.so
b6100000-b6101000 rw-p 0003c000 07:00 300610     /usr/lib/libmumps_common-4.9.2.so
b6101000-b61ff000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 568549     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
b61ff000-b6200000 r--p 000fe000 07:00 568549     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
b6200000-b6201000 rw-p 000ff000 07:00 568549     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
b6201000-b6202000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b6202000-b64d3000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 298969     /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0
b64d3000-b64d7000 rw-p 002d1000 07:00 298969     /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf.0
b64d7000-b64ee000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 590108     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
b64ee000-b64ef000 r--p 00016000 07:00 590108     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
b64ef000-b64f0000 rw-p 00017000 07:00 590108     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
b64f0000-b64f2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b64f2000-b6695000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 590099     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b6695000-b6697000 r--p 001a3000 07:00 590099     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b6697000-b6698000 rw-p 001a5000 07:00 590099     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
b6698000-b669c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b669c000-b66b8000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 554764     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b66b8000-b66b9000 r--p 0001b000 07:00 554764     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b66b9000-b66ba000 rw-p 0001c000 07:00 554764     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
b66ba000-b66e4000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 590110     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
b66e4000-b66e5000 r--p 00029000 07:00 590110     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
b66e5000-b66e6000 rw-p 0002a000 07:00 590110     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
b66e6000-b67be000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 527383     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
b67be000-b67bf000 ---p 000d8000 07:00 527383     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
b67bf000-b67c3000 r--p 000d8000 07:00 527383     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
b67c3000-b67c4000 rw-p 000dc000 07:00 527383     /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
b67c4000-b67cb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b67cb000-b68f2000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300609     /usr/lib/libdmumps-4.9.2.so
b68f2000-b68f3000 r--p 00126000 07:00 300609     /usr/lib/libdmumps-4.9.2.so
b68f3000-b68f4000 rw-p 00127000 07:00 300609     /usr/lib/libdmumps-4.9.2.so
b68f4000-b68f5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b68f5000-b6909000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 521548     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
b6909000-b690a000 r--p 00013000 07:00 521548     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
b690a000-b690b000 rw-p 00014000 07:00 521548     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
b690b000-b690c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b690c000-b70d3000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 298970     /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3gf.0
b70d3000-b70d7000 rw-p 007c6000 07:00 298970     /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3gf.0
b70d7000-b71e4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b71e4000-b72fd000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300909     /lib/libCoinUtils.so.3.8.5
b72fd000-b7300000 rw-p 00118000 07:00 300909     /lib/libCoinUtils.so.3.8.5
b7300000-b734d000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300939     /lib/libOsi.so.1.10.2
b734d000-b734f000 rw-p 0004d000 07:00 300939     /lib/libOsi.so.1.10.2
b734f000-b74b8000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300887     /lib/libClp.so.1.11.5
b74b8000-b74bb000 rw-p 00169000 07:00 300887     /lib/libClp.so.1.11.5
b74bb000-b759d000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300885     /lib/libCgl.so.1.7.2
b759d000-b759f000 rw-p 000e1000 07:00 300885     /lib/libCgl.so.1.7.2
b759f000-b768b000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300877     /lib/libCbc.so.3.7.5
b768b000-b7690000 rw-p 000ec000 07:00 300877     /lib/libCbc.so.3.7.5
b7690000-b7691000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7691000-b76cd000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 300943     /lib/libOsiClp.so.1.11.5
b76cd000-b76ce000 rw-p 0003c000 07:00 300943     /lib/libOsiClp.so.1.11.5
b76ce000-b76da000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 262019     /lib/libOsiCbc.so.3.7.5
b76da000-b76db000 rw-p 0000b000 07:00 262019     /lib/libOsiCbc.so.3.7.5
b76f1000-b76f7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b76f7000-b76f8000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b76f8000-b7718000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 590111     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b7718000-b7719000 r--p 0001f000 07:00 590111     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
b7719000-b771a000 rw-p 00020000 07:00 590111     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
bf951000-bf972000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks to everyone that will answer to my question!

Comment: Far too much complicated code to spot the error, but this sort or thing usually means you have gone past the end of one of your allocatons. Since I can see 5 `delete []` in a 5-line section of code, it's not going to be that easy to figure out which one it is without actually following all of your code. And most likely, you didn't compile with -g, or you would get some more info from gdb.

Comment: Do **not** mix `malloc()` with `delete`!

Comment: Just scrolled down your log-output - seems your code isn't compiling - perhaps you should fix that first.

Comment: This is what is called spaghetti code, unreadable.

Comment: Does the error occur when you **compile** or when you **run**?

Comment: Compile with the -g flag to get a core dump, then walk through it with gdb to see where the crash occurs.

Comment: The error occur when i RUN it! The compile operation doesn't make any kind of error!

Comment: I was saying you can step through the debugger to see where the execution will fault.

Comment: The execution fail on the last delete series and return

Comment: When dumping code on SO for debugging, you could at least make the effort to translate identifiers and messages to English.

Comment: @user4815162342 : the message and identifiers used in this code are striclty connected to the operations research, I don't know how you can understand it :) however, the original problem was created by `else predecessore[i]=1`, in fact now I have an output message that tell me that the array `predecessore` was successfully deleted...but then he can't delete `predecessore` and go in Segmentation Fault. Any idea?

Comment: @LovaJ. : I don't buy the "research" excuse. If it's research, you're going to publish it eventually, and you're ALSO supposed to publish in English. That said, the code is FAR too complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a real mess. That said I see quite a few strange things:

1) Who is allocating `risultato`? Are there three ints allocated for it?

2) Code does this

```
if(numInattivi[i_node[i]][j_node[i]]==nInfrastructureTypes &&
   numInattivi[i_node[i]][j_node[i]]==nInfrastructureTypes)
```

do you really think that checking two times the same thing is going to help?

3) The loop `for(int i=0;i<=level;i++)` uses `level+1` elements, are `value`, `i_node` and `j_node` large enough?

4) You are leaking `numInattivi` (not always). Why all these explicit allocations and pointer fiddling instead of just using `std::vector`? Same speed but a **LOT** easier to use.

5) `predecessore` looks like indexed by node number, but it's sometimes indexed in the same loop directly with `i=0,1,...,level` instead of `i_node[i]` or `j_node[i]`. Is this correct?

6) If the rest of the program is written in the same way then you're probably making a mess of memory everywhere, and there's no hope to get this thing running properly. The fact that you get an error in this function means nothing... doing bad things with memory may trigger a crash millions of executed instructions later.

Comment: 1) The 'risultato' array  is allocated by the main function, and yes:there are only 3 ints inside it.
2) Obviously it's a copy and past error, nothing intentional :D
3) Yes, it's correct
4) I'm not familiar with std::vector, I will read something about it , thanks!
5) Maybe that's the error! In fact, when I use predecessore[i_node[i]] is correct, but it's not correct  
  else
            predecessore[i]=-1;
Soon as possible, I will fix and test it!

Comment: Ok, the original problem was created by `else predecessore[i]=1`, in fact now I have an output message that tell me that the array `predecessore` was successfully deleted...but then he can't delete `predecessore` and go in Segmentation Fault. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix C `malloc` and C++ `delete/delete[]`.

- Memory allocated with `malloc` must be released with `free`.
- Memory allocated with `new` must be released with `delete`.
- Memory allocated with `new[]` must be released with `delete[]`.

Anything else is undefined behaviour.

Now, after you edited the program and made sure that all allocation is done by `new[]` and deletion by `delete[]` then the reason for errors is a buffer overflow somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest, edited the code and the question, but the error still occours after using new in place of malloc !